# Which phoneme/sound is unpronounced in ”prompt”?

Tags: pronunciation, received-pronunciation, consonant-clusters

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/prompt_1?q=prompt

Is the British pronunciation artificial, or is it really how people in England speak on a daily basis? The three consonants [mpt] are to me extremely difficult to pronounce, especially when there's no vowel after the [t] which would break the group into two syllables [prɒmp.tɪd].

My guess is that the true pronunciation skips the [p] sound, thus rendering [prɒmt] or [prɑːmt].

Comment: I don't think there is a "true" pronunciation; I think people use more than one pronunciation. To me (an American), leaving out the /p/ sounds fine, as does leaving it in. But leaving out the /m/ or the /t/ sounds weird.

Comment: Although immediately recognizable by any of us who speak Romance languages, or who are used to reading English from several centuries ago, your use of the noun *vocal* to mean what most native English monoglots today use *vowel* for is somewhat unusual in 21st-century English.  The OED calls this use "rare" today. It has something of an antiquarian feel to it. Educated readers will understand you, of course.

Comment: If the combination *mpt* does not occur in your native language, it is unsurprising that you have difficulty pronouncing it.  Most native English speakers (who have been hearing it since childhood) can say it OK.

Comment: Do you have the same trouble saying *kept* as /kɛpt/ with the P and T together there at the end? It’s definitely a difficult transition, one so hard that the T in that particular cluster often gets deleted in connected speech. This is quite unlike what happens to "weird" words of Greek origin which happen to have that same cluster at the beginning, like *ptomaine* and *pterodactyl*, where we don't even **try** to say their initial P sound, doncha know. :)

Answer (score 3):

I've lived in south-east England my entire life, and have studied a little phonology, and I am convinced that I say /prɒmt/ (which is probably what you expected). This is just one data point and I can't unfortunately tell you whether the "official" IPA is accurate or ideal.

If you want to experiment, compare it with other words with /mt/ like "dreamt" /ˈdɹɛm(p)t/ ?

Comment: You quite probably ***do*** say  /prɒmt/. The OED has the /p/ optional there, so both  /prɒmt/ and  /prɒmpt/ occur. I don't think many folks normally have a /p/ in *dreamt*, but you never know; check out [these](https://youglish.com/pronounce/dreamt/english?) and skip forward to the next example each time you hear the word pronounced in context there. I think the 9th example may have a /p/.

Comment: The nasalization may end before the lips part at the end of /m/. Changes in articulation are not instantaneous or even necessarily closely synchronized.

Answer (score 3):

### I can clearly hear the “mpt” in both the English and American audio

The dictionary also includes “mpt” at the end of their IPA for both. The difference is in the vowel sound preceding the “mpt”.

For what it’s worth, as an Australian, all of the “mpt” are voiced - and we unvoice *everything*.

Clearly, neither recording is “natural” - these people are recording single words for a pronunciation dictionary. This is not the the way people speak everyday and the pronunciation of words in conversation depends on the words around them as much as the word itself. That said, “prompt” is usually encountered at the end of a sentence or phrase so is unlikely to be much changed context.

Comment: Also in Australia - I hear both "mpt" and "mt" at the end of this word from different people at different times.

Comment: When talking about pronunciation, phonetics etc. the words 'voiceless' and 'unvoiced' mean produced without vibration of the vocal cords/folds.  We usually use the verb *elide*. or the noun *elision* to talk about sounds being omitted :)

Comment: (If the ‘mpt’ were actually voiced, they would sound like ‘mbd’…)